# How to check all checkboxes with different names in the same row

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I Have html table as below code, How to check all checkboxes with different names in the same row??
Such as in the row of "Item name 1": if I check the box of "Check all", and then the box of "Date of Start: 2022-04-01" and  the box of " Date of End: 2022-04-30" will be auto checked.

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="tblListForm">
<tbody><tr class="listheader">
<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('tbid[]');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>
<td style="width:10%"><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)">Quantity/Select All</td>
<td style="width:67%"> Item Details </td>
<td style="width:10%; text-align:right;"> Unit Price </td>
<td style="width:13%; text-align:right;"> Sub-total </td>
</tr>
<tr class="evenRow">
<td style="vertical-align:top">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tbid[]" value="238"> 1</td>
<td style="vertical-align:top">
    Item name 1     <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item_no[]" value="1"> Check all<input type="checkbox" name="item_date_start[]" value="2022-04-01">Date of Start: 2022-04-01<input type="checkbox" name="item_date_end[]" value="2022-04-30"> Date of End: 2022-04-30</td>
<td style="vertical-align:top; text-align:right;">
    105.00</td>
<td style="vertical-align:top; text-align:right;">
    105.00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="oddRow">
<td style="vertical-align:top">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tbid[]" value="239"> 1</td>
<td style="vertical-align:top">
    Item name 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item_no[]" value="17"> Check all<input type="checkbox" name="item_date_start[]" value="2022-05-01">Date of Start: 2022-05-01<input type="checkbox" name="item_date_end[]" value="2022-05-31"> Date of End: 2022-05-31</td>
<td style="vertical-align:top; text-align:right;">
    250.00</td>
<td style="vertical-align:top; text-align:right;">
    250.00</td>
</tr>




<tr class="listheader">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top; text-align:right;">  Total (HKD): </td>
<td style="vertical-align:top; text-align:right;">  355.00</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you very much for your sharing & support in advance!

Comment: Unrelated, but all the `style` and `class` attributes do not contribute to the question or the answers. Next, don't hide the code behind long lines and scrollbars. Finally, what's the problem you have? Maybe add another function, checking `item_date_start` and `item_date_end`, or maybe checking all `input`s in a row.

Comment: How can I check the box of name="item_no[]", and then the box of name="item_date_start[]" and the box of name="item_date_end[]" will be auto checked ?

Comment: All the relevant `input`s are inside the same `td`. So you might use [`querySelectorAll`](https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom#querySelectorAll)

Comment: Can you tell me how to write the code ? thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

In this example I added a `<fieldset>` as a (near) parent to the checkboxes. The event listener will look for any change in the form. In the `if()` statement I determine if it was a "Check all" that changed. If so, all the input elements in the closest fieldset should have the same value.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  // the field that just changed
  let field = e.target;
  // somehow determine if the change was
  // on a "Check all" field -- here if class name = "checkall"
  if (field.className == 'checkall') {
    // get the parent fieldset
    let fieldset = e.target.closest('fieldset');
    // for each element in fieldset
    [...fieldset.elements].forEach(input => {
      // all should have the same value as "check all"
      input.checked = field.checked;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align:top">
        <fieldset>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="item_no[]" class="checkall" value="1">Check all</label>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="item_date_start[]" value="2022-04-01">Date of Start: 2022-04-01</label>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="item_date_end[]" value="2022-04-30"> Date of End: 2022-04-30</label>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much first ! But how to control second row and other rows? The field.value will be different  because it is generated by PHP & mysql .

Comment: @CPYBusinessCentre澤昇商務中心 I added a class name "checkall" to the example. So, now the event listener is generic in the sense that there must be a checkbox with the class name "checkall" somewhere and it is a child of a fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

I find a similar answer from the web as below, but how to remove checkbox if click Uncheck, need to rewrite the javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
  ></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div1">
    <input type="button" id="btnDiv1" class="select-all"  value="Check / Uncheck" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Mark
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Frank</div>
<div id="div2">
    <input type="button" id="btnDiv2" class="select-all" value="Check / Uncheck" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />John
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Travis
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Matt</div>
<div id="div3">
    <input type="button" id="btnDiv3" class="select-all" value="Check / Uncheck" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Lee
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Charles</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.select-all').on('click', function () 
{
    $(this).nextAll('.check').prop('checked', true);
});

  </script>


</body>
</html>
```